# Minecraft Won't Boot

Tags: java

I installed Java 8 from the java.com, and I got Minecraft from minecraft.net. But Java will not boot the game! I have clicked on the "run as a program" button and it stays checked, but it never does anything. It just sits there for hours and hours doing nothing. If I uncheck the "run as a program" button, Ubuntu then gives me an error saying that the package (minecraft.jar) is untrusted and dangerous. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I recommend installing OpenJDK instead: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-jdk-7`.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a terminal in the directory where you saved Minecraft.jar, try running it with

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Without further information, there isn't much else that I can recommend. There are a number of reasons why Minecraft may fail to start. By running the command above, it will at the very least provide information on why it's failing. That information can help you search for a solution, many of which are linked as 'related questions' in the sidebar here.

I can say from personal experience that Oracle's Java 8 works fine with Minecraft in Ubuntu, if it's correctly configured. Indeed, Java 8 is required for many [mods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_%28video_gaming%29) for Minecraft to function.

Comment: I know you can't comment (and yes it's a stupid rule), but unless you have an actual solution, you need to post comments. Taking out the last sentence you have will make it an acceptable answer, even if it doesn't end up solving the problem.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Perhaps that helps? Running from the command line is an actual solution, in that it's likely his problem is due to the Gnome file browser failing to execute .jar files with java. This is the most fool-proof way I know of making sure that it's actually running with java, and it will tell you why it failed if it fails.

Comment: yes, that's why I suggested taking out the last sentence. You did a good job of replacing it